# Objective C memory layout: Meaning of the highest 2 bits of a 64bit pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

While debugging a bunch of `NSIndexPath` objects I noticed that one of them had an unusual pointer.

One of the index paths had the address 0xc000000388400016. So it has the two highest bits set to 1. Out of interest I would love to know what this means. I know the lowest bit is used for tagged pointers, but the lowest bit is 0 in this case. Which objects get mapped to this high address range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify things a bit for people who might land here: It is in fact a tagged pointer even though the low bit is set to 0. Apparently Apple changed the implementation for tagged pointer at some point so that all iOS based systems (iOS, tvOS, watchOS) and macOS starting from 10.11(?) use the high bits to identify a tagged pointer.

This is the answer I got from Joe Groff on twitter. Source: https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/897856728586309632

Answer (score 1):

It is tagged pointer objects in 64-bit code.

Check more here: [Github](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/objc-internal.h)

```
OBJC_TAG_NSAtom            = 0, 
OBJC_TAG_1                 = 1, 
OBJC_TAG_NSString          = 2, 
OBJC_TAG_NSNumber          = 3, 
OBJC_TAG_NSIndexPath       = 4, 
OBJC_TAG_NSManagedObjectID = 5, 
OBJC_TAG_NSDate            = 6, 
OBJC_TAG_7                 = 7
```

Comment: Yeah, the important part here is that this changed though. In the past, tagged pointers where using the lower bits. Now apparently they are using the higher bits. (See my own answer)

Comment: Tagged pointers are changed often. It is internal thing, Apple can do what ever they want with it (as long as it is compatible :) Also, info from Joe is info from the source ;) Also, I would not recommend to use "hacks" with tagged pointers for any other purposes but education :)